How to `apk fetch` exact versions of a package?
I want to fetch .apk files for a certain package at a certain version, including all their dependencies.
I can do this to install an exact version: apk add nano=8.0-r0
I can do this to get the package for nano and all its dependencies: apk fetch --recursive nano.
So why can't I run apk fetch --recursive nano=8.0-r0? It just errors with nano=8.0-r0: unable to select package (or its dependencies), in exactly the same way it would for a non-existing package.
I know the default Alpine repos never store more than a single version, which would make the question moot, but I'm running a custom repository with multiple versions.
Because most packages follow a strict naming scheme, I can think of many hacks around this missing functionality, but I'm looking for a more reliable solution.

After much research, it turns out it's not possible, so I wrote it: https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/apk-tools/-/merge_requests/227. (Once merged, I'll post it as an answer).
